What version of the Google Analytics for Firebase iOS SDK is used in the latest Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Analytics nuget package?
I received a notification on Firebase saying:
Action Recommended: Update the Google Analytics for Firebase (GA4F) iOS SDK
Update to version 10.24.0 or later to avoid potential impact resulting from privacy manifest policies after May 1, 2024.
I am in the middle of updating to MAUI and will probably use a different package, but it definitely won't be ready for production by then.
I don't see any info regarding the sdk version used in this package. So my question is, how can I find that out?

Are you going to submit a new build after May 1 and before you change the package you are using?  Privacy manifests are only required for new submissions after may 1.  Old releases will continue to operate.

The package repo lists 8.10 as the analytics version.

@Paulw11 There will most likely be some overlap between builds and updating the package. So the package version corresponds to the firebase sdk version? I didn't think that was the case because Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics is on v121.3.0 but I guess that actually corresponds to v21.3.0?

The package is just a wrapper to the Google library. There is not necessarily any alignment between the package version and the version of the Google library that it wraps,  but in this case they seem to have linked the version numbers.  The package GitHub page lists analytics 8.10 as the version that it wraps. Given that it hasn't been updated for a while I would assume that this is still the case.

You should able to find a plugin.xml file within a package where you can find the necessary info that includes which version of FirebaseAnalytics has been used for ios by this package.
